# What options excluding the UIWebView control do I have to integrate google maps?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, uiwebview

I'm starting to do some google maps integration in my latest iPhone project and I'm asking this question to find out what the best practice around this is today in 3.1.3 or 4.x

If my only option is the UIWebView do I need to worry about my api key (assuming it would need to be included to run the application)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you consider using MapKit? It's quite straight forward and you don't need apikey or any additional setup.

Just use it in a basic UIView that will be your MKMapViewDelegate and GMapCustomAnnotationViewDelegate... and with something like, in your init:

```
gMapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
gMapView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:gMapView]
```

you're done.

Comment: Not sure how I didn't see this control sooner - it was directly under the UIWebView in interface builder :)